# Does Linq optimizes execution based on real collection type?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Linq to objects works on any IEnumerable object. The variables

```
string[] foo = new string[] { };
```

and

```
var bar = new List<string>();
```

are both `IEnumerable<string>`, but if I want to know how many items each one of them has, I can use `Length` property on the array and `Count` property on the list. Or I can use the `Count` method from Linq, which will work for both.

The question is: does Linq provides some kind of optimization, such as implement different algorithms for every method, calling one or another depending on the actual type of the object being queried?

I imagine something like this:

```
if (obj is Array<T>)
    DoSomethingForArray(obj as Array<T>);
else if (obj is List<T>)
    DoSomethingForList(obj as List<T>);
else if (obj is Collection<T>)
    DoSomethingForCollection(obj as Collection<T>);
else
   DoSomethingThatWorksForAnyIEnumerable(obj);
```

Comment: side-note: array also implements `ICollection`, hence it also has a `Count` property.,y you just need to cast it accordingly.

Comment: with a disassembler, like ildasm, you can look at the source code. then you see the different optimizations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is: it depends - The Linq extension method `Count()` checks if the type implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` and uses the `Count` property of that if possible, but it doesn't optimize for every possible scenario.

Comment: Which Count() are you talking about? Wouldn't the Count() method called be determined based on the type of object it was being called upon?

Comment: Brian is talking about `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)`. And to be more precise, `Count()` (currently) first checks if the type implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` and if so, uses the `Count` property. Otherwise it loops over the complete collection.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for the additional info. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok, I think that clarification would help.